# Right way of using Google Storage on a GCE VM

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to know the right/best way of having one machine copying data to Google Storage.

I need one machine to be able to write to a bucket, but not be able to create or delete other buckets.

While researching, I found out that you should create a account service so this account can log in to GC and then use the storage.

But the problem is, when the machine is from GCE, there are scopes. When setting up the scope "Default" it can Read from Google Storage, but can not write to it. Even after authenticated with a service account. 
When the scope is Devstorage.read_write  now the machine can create and remove buckets from that storage without login. I find that to risk.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The core problem here is that the "write" scope covers both write and delete, and that the GCE service account is likely a member of project-editors, which can create and delete buckets.  It sounds like what you want to do is restrict a service account to only being able to affect a single bucket.  You should be able to do this with these steps:

1. Create a service account in your project (and save the private key file).
2. In the permissions page for the project, make sure that service account is not a project editor for your project.
3. Using an account that does have full permissions to your project, create the bucket, then grant the service account write access to the bucket.  Example gsutil commands to do this:

   `gsutil mb gs://yourbucket`

   `gsutil acl ch -u your-service-account-name@gserviceaccount.com:W gs://yourbucket`
4. Create a VM that does **not** have a GCE service account enabled.
5. Push the service account's private key file to that VM.
6. On the VM, `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=your-key-file.json`

Now `gsutil` commands run on the VM should be able to write to (and delete) objects in that bucket, but not any other buckets in your project.

Comment: Thanks, for the info, but if I do this, I lose read access to Storage and Cloud User Accounts, write access to Cloud Logging and Monitoring. Otherwise no API access. Those are default api access from a service account. We see what is the best way to go, need to see if any developer are using any of the permissions above.

Comment: If you need to use the GCE VM service account for access to other services, you could just remove the [GoogleCompute] entry from /etc/boto.cfg on the VM so that gsutil doesn't look for the GCE VM service account.  Then you could use the GCE VM service account for access to other services, and the service account you created for writing to the Google Cloud Storage bucket via gsutil.